# Проблемы с кодировкой при добавлении заголовка в response mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, angularjs, http, mvc

Проблема состоит в следующем.
Я посылаю запрос на сервер следующим образом.

```
 $http({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                mimeType: "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
                params: { groupId: groupId },
                headers: {
                    "Header-Type": "charset=UTF-8",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en,ru-ru"
                }
            }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.data !== "") {
                    $scope.filterDetails = result.data;
                    filterList = JSON.parse(result.headers("filterList"));
                    $scope.isListEmpty = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.isListEmpty = true;
                }
            }, function (result) {
                alert(result.data);
            });
```

в контроллере добавляю заголовок filterList.

```
 List<SiteFilter> result = SiteFilterRepository.GetFilterList(groupId);
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string str = serializer.Serialize(result);
            Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            Response.AppendHeader("filterList", str);
            Response.Charset = "utf-8";
            if (result != null)
            {
                return View("~/Views/SavedSearches/SavedSearchesDetails.cshtml", groupId);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("~/Views/SavedSearches/SavedSearchesDetails.cshtml", groupId);
            }
```

Который выглядит следующим образом "`[{\"Id\":85,\"FilterGroupId\":68,\"Parameter\":\"CallId\",\"Condition\":\"Равно\",\"Value\":\"4\"}]"`

В строке   `filterList = JSON.parse(result.headers("filterList"));` получаю

```
[{"Id":85,"FilterGroupId":68,"Parameter":"CallId","Condition":"Ð Ð°Ð²Ð½Ð¾","Value":"4"}]
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему слудующим образом   `filterList = decodeURIComponent(escape(result.headers("filterList")));`
то есть сначал конвертирую Response в escape последовательность потому,в строку в формате ISO-8859-1.Почему JS воспринимает только эту кодировку пока не разобрался.